# «Мозорный уроз». Как кавычить оговорку (повторяемую и разъясняемую) в тексте?

Tags: пунктуация

> Моя Алёнушка спрашивала своего заморского жениха: «Что больше всего тебе 
>   понравилось на моей родине?» И влюблённый, глядя мне в глаза, держа
>   меня за руку, обычно проникновенно отвечал: «Мозорный уроз…» (вместо
>   морозный узор). И ведь все принцы, как сговорившись, проговаривали эту
>   чушь! Видно, как-то так язык сам складывается, если по два спектакля
>   каждый день давать. Уж и не знаю. Но знаю одно – это поворотная
>   реплика для моей роли, потому что после неё я придумываю себе такой
>   наряд, чтобы повторял он узоры мороза на стекле или мозорные урозы,
>   тут уж как получится.

*...Чтобы повторял он узоры мороза на стекле или мозорные урозы,
тут уж как получится.*

Что тут с кавычками? Иными знаками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется,  "мозорные урозы" - это скорее цитата (чужие слова), чем термин, поэтому эти слова должны быть в кавычках.

И попутно еще два замечания.

1. Очевидно, Аленушка - это роль, которую играет рассказчица, но все равно я бы сказал: "глядя **ей** в глаза, держа **ее** за руку", ведь ответ адресовался не актрисе, а Аленушке и произносил его не актер, а "влюблённый", т. е. принц. Тот факт, что именно рассказчица выступала в роли Аленушки, не имеет значения, принц говорил бы те же слова и Аленушке-дублерше.
2. "Поворотный момент", "после неё я придумываю себе такой наряд". Какой момент? Что значит "после нее"? Реплика повторяется из раза в раз (принц "**обычно** проникновенно отвечал"). Чтобы исправить эту логическую неточность, нужно дать ссылку на момент, когда эта реплика была произнесена первый раз, например:

**Но знаю одно: появление этой реплики** (может лучше - оговорки?) **- поворотный момент для моей роли, потому что после этого я *придумала*** (а не придумываю) **себе такой наряд, чтобы повторял он узоры мороза на стекле или "мозорные урозы", тут уж как получится.**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, по-моему, кавычки не нужны. Неологизм ввели, объяснили его значение, дальше используем как обычное слово. Подобное можем наблюдать в различных договорах и научных работах, где после ввода и объяснения нового термина далее его используют абсолютно свободно.

Answer (score 1):

*Что тут с кавычками?*
Про кавычки *Марк Из* всё сказал: коротко и доступно.
Наверное, тут можно провести аналогию с аббревиатурой: при первом упоминании её расшифровывают ["мозорный уроз" - в кавычках; прямая речь] и уже потом используют вовсю [мозорный уроз - без кавычек; нет прямой речи].

*И ведь все принцы, **как сговорившись, проговаривали** эту чушь!*
Не лучше ли вместо повтора использовать "все как один", с усилением?

*...после неё я придумываю себе такой наряд*
Возникает некая двусмысленность: Алёнушка после ***каждой*** поворотной реплики (произнесенной в очередной раз) придумывает себе наряд.
Возможно, лучше использовать *"придумала"?*

**Дополнение**

Моя Алёнушка спрашивала своего заморского жениха: «Что больше всего тебе понравилось на моей родине?» И влюблённый, глядя мне в глаза **и** держа меня за руку, обычно проникновенно отвечал: «Мозорный уроз…» (вместо морозный узор). И ведь все принцы, **все как один,** проговаривали эту чушь! **Похоже,** **что язык сам как-то так** складывается, если по два спектакля каждый день давать **, уж** и не знаю. **Но знаю одно: для моей роли - это** **поворотная реплика**, потому что после неё я **придумала** себе такой наряд, чтобы повторял он узоры мороза на стекле или мозорные урозы **. Тут** уж как получится.

Возможно, что-то окажется для Вас полезным.